# How exactly does the principle of superposition work for first-order ordinary differential equations?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I understand how the principle of superposition works for linear and homogeneous second-order differential equations. For example,

$y'' + y' + y = 0$ has a solution of the form $y(x) = c_1y_1(x) + c_2y_2(x)$, where $y_1(x) = e^{r_1x}$ and $e^{r_2x}$.

Now consider the simple equation $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} -x = 0$, with solution $y(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + c$

This equation is homogeneous and linear (I also double checked with WolframAlpha), so the principle of superposition must apply. However, a function that is a constant multiple of the solution, such as $g(x) = 2y(x) = 2x^2 + 2c = 2x^2 + c$ does not solve the equation.

We get the result of $g'(x) = 2y'(x) = 2x$, but from the original differential equation, the derivative of our solution has to equal $x$, not $2x$.

I am not new to differential equations. I have taken courses in differential equations and partial differential equations, as well as additional courses that utilize modeling of differential equations in engineering and physics. I will be teaching a differential equations course next semester, so when I was making lecture notes, I stumbled upon this problem.

Comment: Your equation $y’(x) = x$ isn’t homogeneous.

Comment: And $y^2+y+1=0$ surely isn't what you meant to write.

Comment: @Aruralreader isn't $y'(x) - x = 0 $ homogeneous? WolframAlpha confirms this too. And yes, I did mean to write $y'' + y' + y = 0$

Comment: There seem to be different definitions of _homogeneous_ for first order equations.

Comment: Asking "intelligent" computers math questions is so far not a very good idea.